# Inner join of 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

## Tables

**Production**

[image]

**Category**

[image]

**Orders**

[image]

**OrderDetails**

[image]

I've made SalesView as follow

```
create view salesView as select o.oID, p.name as product, od.sell_price as price, od.qty as quantity, o.order_date
    from orderDetails od inner join
    orders o on o.oID = od.oID,
    production p where = p.ID = od.pID;
```

As od ( instance of Table OrderDetails ) does not contains reference to Category table. How can I add column 'Category' in SalesView?

Now,

```
select * from SalesView;
```

[image]

I want to add 'Category' column in it.

I've tried...

```
create view salesView as select o.oID, p.name as product, c.name as category, od.sell_price as price, od.qty as quantity, o.order_date
    from orderDetails od inner join
    orders o on o.oID = od.oID,
    production p where = p.ID = od.pID,
    category c where c.ID = ???
```

Comment: First off don't mix notations.  use ,'s or use inner joins but not both.  You're using pre ansi 92 and ansi 92 standards in one query.  This isn't generally supported.

Comment: the images whicy you uploaded are cant seen please do not upload it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix notations/standards.  To add category, simply inner join category to your production table.  This assumes all productions will have a category; otherwise you may want to left (outer) join.

```
create view salesView as 
SELECT o.oID
     , p.name as product
     , c.name as category
     , od.sell_price as price
     , od.qty as quantity
     , o.order_date
     , c.name
FROM orderDetails od 
INNER JOIN orders o 
   on o.oID = od.oID
INNER JOIN Production p 
   on p.ID = od.pID
INNER JOIN Category c
   on c.ID = P.catID
WHERE...
```

Don't do this:

```
create view salesView as select o.oID, p.name as product, od.sell_price as price, od.qty as quantity, o.order_date
    from orderDetails od inner join --<See the inner join
    orders o on o.oID = od.oID, --<See the ,  (don't mix standards!)
    production p where = p.ID = od.pID;
```

Notice the difference in standards: https://gerardnico.com/data/type/relation/sql/join_default_ansi92_comparison

Comment: Thank you very much. :)